# Comparing Files inside Tar on Unix

Tags: linux, files, tar, diff, file-comparison

I want to know how can I compare some files inside a tar one with these same files in one directory and if these file exists in the directory, proceed to delete them.

I tried using **diff** and **tar -tvf** command, but, I cannot find the way of how can I do this.

Please, someone help me.

Regards,

Comment: Do you care about comparing the contents of the files, or are you just going to delete the file from the directory if the tar contains a file by the same *name* (regardless of contents)?

Comment: If the file exists inside the tar file, the goal is delete the file from the directory, and not the tar one. The comparing needs to be in bytes size.